# How do I get a random word of a certain length from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random, string-length

I'd like to get a random string of a certain length (determined by an input field) from an array of strings. Is there any way to do this without creating a new array containing all the words of that length then selecting from that?

I am currently able to get a random word from the array with this:

```
var word = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I implement the word length specification?

You loop picking up words randomly unless length meets your requirements or you i.e. keep words grouped by length (i.e. multi dimensional array). Then you just need to pick up the right array (your `arr`) and pick as you did so far

Answer (score 0):

Why not Mapping it first and then Apply your call?

```
// Example: 
const requiredLength = 5,
const originalArr = ['lalal', 'hehehehehe', 'uhuhuhuh', 'uooou'];

const arr = originalArr.map(word => word.length === requiredLength);
// arr = ['lalal','uooou'];

const word = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
```

Comment: Did you mean `Array.filter`? `originalArr.map(word => word.length === requiredLength);` returns `[true, false, false, true]`.